# How can I set the color for a single data point in a series in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, embedded-resource

I decided to create a bar chart inside my Google Sheet, read it in using the Script Editor tool & modify it in place, as I felt this would be easier than creating one from scratch & then adding it to the Sheet. Turns out, using the UI to create the Chart has been much easier than scripting it.

Now, I would like to set the color of only 1 of the data points in a single series to be red, when it's over a certain threshold. So far, I have found that the following snippet can set the color of the entire series, but I can't find anything to set the color of just one data point:

```
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
     .setOption('series.0.color', 'red')
     .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

If I try to replace setOption with setColors (.setColors(['green', 'red'])), I get an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot find function setColors in object EmbeddedChartBuilder.
```

[According to this reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder#setcolorscssvalues), setColors can only be used when creating a new chart.

There are [numerous articles online](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-change-data-point-colors-in-charts/) about how to change the color of a single data point in a bar chart from the UI. Any pointers on how to change the color programmatically would be much appreciated.

Comment: To recreate what you're trying to do, it would be helpful to provide a minimal way to reproduce the chart you are working with.  If you replace the `.setColors(['green', 'red'])` with `.setOption('series', { 0: { color: 'green' }, 1: { color: 'red' } })` does that do what you want it to do?

Comment: you can use a [style column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) to change the color of a single data point...

Comment: @dwmorrin I believe this snippet [.setOption('series', { 0: { color: 'green' }, 1: { color: 'red' } })] will achieve the same effect as [.setOption('series.0.color', 'red')], i.e. change the color of the entire series, not a single data point.

Comment: @WhiteHat I checked out the link, but I believe roles are for web charts only. I'm trying to use the EmbeddedChart in Google Apps Script, which seems to be a trimmed down version of the web chart.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: Doh! I figured it out. If you record a macro and set a data point color using the wizard on the right, then the macro code does not show the series being colored. But if you do it by right clicking on the series then doing it, that works. This is how to do it: `.setOption('series.0.items.2.color', "red")`

Answer (score 2):

This is how you set the color of a specific series:

```
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('series.0.color', 'red')
    .setOption('series.0.items.0.color', 'blue')
    .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```