# Is there a way to automate the data point colours for a bar chart with Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I'm just trying to learn some new stuff with Google Sheets to try and make things a bit fancier and more visually friendly.

My question is if there's a way to automate the data points that you can add in manually. Like in the image  below.

[Correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhI9i.png)

The issue with this is if the data changes due to formatting/sorting then the colours will stay assigned to the same "bar" even if the data changes. I want the bar chart to be created with the colour from the 3rd column being the colour displayed on the chart. So for example; John's bar would always be Red, no matter the position in the chart.

I have used the Google Apps Script to try and get something to work, but I always get the first colour, so not sure whether it's just a limitation or there's something I'm doing wrong.

Here's an example data set to work with

| Name | Goals | Team |
| John   | 8   | Red |
| Doe   | 5   | Blue |
| Jane   | 2   | Green |

This is an example script that I've played about with. It may be complete rubbish and not needed.

```
function createColorBarChart() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:C4"); // Update range

  // Create a new chart builder
  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart()
      .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR)
      .addRange(dataRange)
      .setNumHeaders(1)
      .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
      .setOption("title", "Top 3")
      .setOption("hAxis.title", sheet.getRange("B1").getValue())
      .setOption('legend', {position: 'None'});

  var dataTableBuilder = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, sheet.getRange("C1").getValue()) // Use 'Team' as the X-axis label
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, sheet.getRange("B1").getValue());

  // Define custom colors for each team
  var colors = {
    'Blacks': 'black',
    'Greens': 'green',
    'Purples': 'purple',
    'Yellows': 'yellow',
    'Oranges': 'orange',
    'Blues': 'blue',
    'Reds': 'red',
    'Whites': 'white'
  };

  // Get the data (excluding the header row)
  var data = dataRange.getValues().slice(1);

  // Initialize the chart series
  var series = [];
  
  // Iterate through the data and create series with custom colors
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];

    // Look up the team based on the name
    var team = rowData[2];

    // Create a series with custom color for the current team
    var seriesOptions = {
      color: colors[team]
    };
    
    series.push(seriesOptions);
  }

  // Set the series options for the chart
  chartBuilder.setOption('series', series);

  // Build the chart and insert it into the sheet
  var chart = chartBuilder.build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

EDIT: Found a similar (if not exact) question, which confirms this doesn't have programmatic access.

[Is there a way to format data points when creating a chart using Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328129/is-there-a-way-to-format-data-points-when-creating-a-chart-using-apps-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing image, table, and script and your goal. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi, no need to apologise at all. I want the bar chart to be created with the colour from the 3rd column being the colour displayed on the chart. So for example; John's bar would always be Red. 
The script may be complete rubbish and not needed.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.