# Visualize product type in Google spreadsheet chart

Tags: google-sheets, charts

For the following data

| Date of sale | Vegetable | Weight | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 | carrot | 80 | 382 |
| 2024-01-30 | cabbage | 22 | 312 |
| 2024-01-19 | potato | 46 | 324 |
| 2024-01-16 | cabbage | 22 | 312 |
| 2024-01-11 | carrot | 44 | 312 |

I could obtain the following chart

[image: vegetable sales]

by

1. Adding X axis: "Date of sale"
2. Series -- "Date of sale"  -- remove
3. Uncheck: treat label as text

Note that the vegetable names are shown as labels. My question is, is there any way to make the vegatable names more visually stand-out? For example, with a pattern , shade, or even shown as another color-coded data sery? By doing this, the reader would be able to easily connect products with seasons when the data span a few years.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: Change each data point's bar color

There doesn't seem to be a way to change the format of each data label (the vegetable names, to be more specific) in Google Sheets. Any changes made would have to apply to all data label. One workaround is to change the bar color of each data point instead.

Here's a sample GIF showing how to modify each data point in Google Sheets:
[image]

If you're interested in changing the color of each data point via Google Apps Script, do take a look at the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56720313/how-can-i-set-the-color-for-a-single-data-point-in-a-series-in-google-sheets-scr) for an example of how to do it.

Comment: Changing colors via script would be a good idea. I was considering using pivot tables, but it seems that I have to show data in two charts.